# How many solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{1000}x_i>500$ where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of solutions to the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{1000}x_i>500$ where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$.

My attempt: We need to pick anywhere from $501$ to $1000$ "$1$"s so the answer should be $\sum_{k=501}^{1000}$ $1000\choose k$ but I'm not certain how to continue with this sum.

My other thought is that it should be (a bit less than) half of all the possibilities because for every choice of over $500$ "$1$"s there is a similar choice with over $500$ "$0$"s, so the answer should be $2^{1000}/2$ minus the number of solutions that equal $500$ exactly: $1000 \choose 500$. Are both of these correct and should amount to the same thing? I tried doing something like:

$\sum_{k=501}^{1000}$ $1000\choose k$$=\sum_{k=0}^{1000}$ $1000\choose k$ $-$ $\sum_{k=0}^{500}$$1000\choose k$ $=$ $2^{1000}$ $-$ $\sum_{k=0}^{500}$$1000\choose k$  but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: The main point here is that $1000$ and $500$ are in a specific relation to each other. The one is exactly twice as large as the other. In probabilistic terms, you toss a fair coin $1000$ times. With which probability would you have more than $500$ heads? Less than $500$ heads? Exactly $500$ heads?

Comment: The order isn't important? So, $(0, 1, 1, \dots, 1)$ and $(1, 1, \dots, 1, 0)$ are treated as one solution for $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_{1000})$? In that case, wouldn't the answer be just $500$? (Because there's one solution for $\sum x_i = 501$, one solution for $\sum x_i = 502$, etc.)

Comment: Without extra specification in the problem I would interpret the problem the same way as @GennadiyAverkov. Order matters, and you are expected to use the symmetry (plus a bit of extra).

Comment: `Sum[Binomial[1000, i], {i, 501, 1000}]`  `5222398915458618319984317898487021415058948054304393893715055504298442\
5412719195155166856521162281055552920615452549610735346215534362302592\
1734167749952816425545114528023962603245607049131662726679480399596348\
8689505448140821239839325471475928818081102140310541702652528972701771\
663740486702923426528`

Comment: I think that I've made a mistake. Saying the order isn't important means exactly the opposite of what I thought: We want to count all the possible orders, since all of them will be a solution to the problem. I'm editing the main post

Comment: @GennadiyAverkov isn't that what I did? $2^{1000} /2 - $ $1000 \choose 500$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have read the post a bit more carefully. This easier formula was hidden in the middle of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of solutions be $S$. Then $$S={1000 \choose 501}+{1000 \choose 502}+...+{1000 \choose 1000}$$ $$S={1000 \choose 499}+{1000 \choose 498}+...+{1000 \choose 0}$$ $$S+S+{1000 \choose 500}=2^{1000}$$ $$S=\frac{2^{1000}-{1000 \choose 500}}{2}$$